# Imageview rotation

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to rotate the imageview  by detecting the user's gesture when he touches the imageview and moves it to a new position.So I want to rotate it angularly accordingly.But my problem is that I am using MinSDK version as 8 and hence cannot use the functions getX(),getY(),setPivotX(), setPivotY() for measuring the requires angle.

Is there any alternate to the above mentioned functions in order to calculate the angle.

Answer (score 3):

It's better just to rotate the image inside ImageView, instead of ImageView itself, and move the ImageView while under gesture dragging.

Refer to my article on Rotating Image: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/image-processing-rotate-image-on-the-fly/

Comment: Good job answering questions these last few days, also nice blog!